# C++, why does adding an int to an unsigned int. produce a weird value?

Tags: equation, unsigned, signed

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned u = 10;
    int i = -42;
    cout << i + i << endl; // prints -84
    cout << u + i << endl; // if 32-bit ints, prints 4294967264
}
```

I have that code and on the second arithmetic equation 'u+i' I get the value "4294967264," now why is that? Why?

Can you explain? 
I'm only so far in C++ so please explain step by step and refrain from using complicated terminology! Please!

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: Lets say -32 just to be simple. I don't really understand how it gets to 4294967264 and I'm not too deep in it. Mind explaining some?

Comment: How can an unsigned have the value -32? You won't be able to get a comprehensible answer to this question until your assumptions are rooted out. You recognize that `unsigned` can hold values `int` can't hold, and `int` can hold values that `unsigned` can't hold, right? So neither type could guarantee that addition always gave the right value. Therefore, sometimes the value will be wrong.

Comment: So the values like this : 4294967264 is a wrong answer and is just given out randomly to this one problem or something? Unsigned means no negative only positives 0 - positives right? So therefore it will always give 4294967264?

Comment: No. It's the result of underflow. It's just like an odometer rolling over from its highest value to its lowest value, except it rolled under from its lowest value to its highest value.

Comment: I suppose I get it slightly more. I will wait for other answers thanks.